# Falling Raindrop with Asymptotic Acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, forces, acceleration

I am given a falling raindrop that is gaining mass proportional to the product of its surface area and its velocity.  I am assuming down is the positive direction.  So, $m'=4\pi\alpha r^2v$.  From this one can show that $r'=\alpha v$.  I am asked to show that the acceleration is asymptotically approaching some value.  In this case
$$
mg=(mv)'=m'v+mv'.
$$
I can solve for $v'$ to get
$$
v'=g-\frac{m'}{m}v=g-\frac{4\pi\alpha r^2v}{\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}}v=g-\frac{3\alpha v^2}{r}.
$$
This leads me to believe that $\dfrac{v^2}{r}$ must tend to some value.

I can answer the question using cases, like if $v\to \infty$, then $r\to \infty$, and I can use L'Hopital's Rule.  Or $v\to 0$ and $r\to 0$.  I feel there should be a way to do this without separate cases and that I am missing the point of the problem with my solution.  Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: FYI, I think you left out density when substituting for $m$.

Comment: @AlanRominger I was assuming that the density of water is $1$.

Comment: You don't seem to take into account that as the drop grows, so does its cross section.

Comment: I see absolutely no reason why the acceleration would take on some 'asymptotical value'. $mg=ma$, always. Now if a *drag force* was in play (like in Real Life) then that would be a different matter altogether...

Comment: @Gert The cross section would grow as its radius does.

Comment: @Gert The "drag force" is provided by the added mass which has zero momentum as it joins the droplet.

Comment: Did you try taking the derivative of $v^2/r$? It it's zero, that term is constant.

Comment: @Spirko: I was referring to the *viscous drag* in air (Stokes Law).

Comment: I think the OP has done things right but has hit a DE that isn't integrable.

Comment: @Gert Without drag and without accruing mass, the acceleration would just be $a=g$, as you said.  With mass accrual, $F=ma$ doesn't work unless you include a force due to impacts with the mist.  By using $F=\dot{p}$, the impact forces due to mass accrual are accounted for.  I think he's basically analyzing the same situation as this:  https://www.physics.harvard.edu/uploads/files/undergrad/probweek/sol5.pdf.  The missing equation is the derivative of $M=\rho (\textrm{Volume})$.

Comment: Boy, I have been trying to work though this problem but I haven't been able to get anywhere in answering the question about the terminal velocity here. Sure hope that you post the solution.